# Swift validate 2 uitextfield password during text entry

Tags: swift, validation, passwords, textfield

i have 2 textfield which contain 1 input pin and 1 re type pin, i try to validate with shouldChangeCharactersIn so if the pin not the same, it will automatically show a little text message said the pin not the same. well it works but not quite, because if i just type 6 pin in my input pin, and i also type 6 pin in re type pin, (in this case i deliberate to type the wrong pin) and the message wont pop out, but if i type more then 6 times, let say in the 7 number than the message will show up, why is that i dont understand.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    

    if textConfirmPIN.text!.count == 6 && textPIN.text!.count == 6 {
        if textConfirmPIN.text != textPIN.text{
            self.showError(message: "PIN is not the same")
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

sorry for my bad english, but can anyone tell me whats going on? thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use textfield editing changed event not `shouldChangeCharactersIn`, because when you check `textConfirmPIN.text!.count` in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` the last typed char still not present yet until return true

that's why it called when you typed 7th character

[image]

Comment: ahhh okay2 now i see, thanks for the answer sir i spend whole day try to figure this out